# ¿Cambiar inter-espaciado en justificación CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando en el documento .css, pero mi párrafo al "justificarlo" no queda agradable ya que adiciona demasiados espacios.

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
  <p class="lead" align="justify">Un año después Larry y Sergey, ahora los estudiantes de Stanford ciencias de la computación graduado, han comenzado a colaborar en un motor de búsqueda llamado BackRub. BackRub ha operado en los servidores de Stanford por más de un año-finalmente ha
    ocupado demasiado ancho de banda para adaptarse a la universidad.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con demasiados espacios? yo veo el texto formateado de manera correcta

Comment: Con la propiedad word-spacing, puedes controlar el espacio entre las palabras, pero no creo que te ayude con tu problema, igual revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: @LeviArista el inter-espaciado que automáticamente genera la justificación, mi pregunta es si ese inter-espaciado se puede ajustar o modificar a gusto.

Comment: Ah, pues parece que no, a no ser que te sirva la respuesta que te han dado, podrias intentar con metodos mas complicados, pero seria complicarte la vida por las puras xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más rápida de controlar el espacio entre las palabras es con la propiedad word-spacing, pero no es la solución mágica que buscas, ya que los ríos de blancos son propios del texto justificado en espacios angostos, lo mejor es que determines cuando es demasiado usando media queries para que se justifiquen más a la izquierda.

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: arial;
}

.col-lg-4{
  width: calc(100% / 4.1);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.lead{
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}

.ws01{
    word-spacing: .05em;
}
.ws02{
    word-spacing: .5em;
}

.ws03{
    word-spacing: 1em;
}
.ws04{
    word-spacing: 2em;
}

@media (max-width: 840px){
  .col-lg-4{
    width: calc(100% / 2.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
  <p class="lead ws01" align="justify">Un año después Larry y Sergey, ahora los estudiantes de Stanford ciencias de la computación graduado, han comenzado a colaborar en un motor de búsqueda llamado BackRub. BackRub ha operado en los servidores de Stanford por más de un año-finalmente ha ocupado demasiado ancho de banda para adaptarse a la universidad.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
  <p class="lead ws02" align="justify">Un año después Larry y Sergey, ahora los estudiantes de Stanford ciencias de la computación graduado, han comenzado a colaborar en un motor de búsqueda llamado BackRub. BackRub ha operado en los servidores de Stanford por más de un año-finalmente ha ocupado demasiado ancho de banda para adaptarse a la universidad.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
  <p class="lead ws03" align="justify">Un año después Larry y Sergey, ahora los estudiantes de Stanford ciencias de la computación graduado, han comenzado a colaborar en un motor de búsqueda llamado BackRub. BackRub ha operado en los servidores de Stanford por más de un año-finalmente ha ocupado demasiado ancho de banda para adaptarse a la universidad.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
  <p class="lead ws04" align="justify">Un año después Larry y Sergey, ahora los estudiantes de Stanford ciencias de la computación graduado, han comenzado a colaborar en un motor de búsqueda llamado BackRub. BackRub ha operado en los servidores de Stanford por más de un año-finalmente ha ocupado demasiado ancho de banda para adaptarse a la universidad.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Edgar, me ha servido de algo, como dices, no completamente pero si parcialmente, saludos